# MS SQL Query not working when i put where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I am writing a simple query to fetch Amount for a particular date. The query works well without where clause. But after putting where clause it does not fetches any record. Pls help.

My Query is

```
Select 
OSTotal as RevenueDaily,
systemlastedittime as Lastedittime
from AccTransactionHeader where systemlastedittime = '09/02/2015'
```

Also datatype of `systemlastedittime` is `DT`, I am not aware about its format whether it is in `ddmmyyyy` or `mmddyyyy` format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Format should be `yyyy-MM-dd`

```
Select OSTotal as RevenueDaily, systemlastedittime as
 Lastedittime from AccTransactionHeader where
 CAST(systemlastedittime as DATE) ='2015-02-09'
```

Answer (score 0):

you might also try

```
set dateformat ymd
```

before your select statement.
taken from MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query:

```
Select OSTotal as RevenueDaily, systemlastedittime as Lastedittime 
from AccTransactionHeader 
where CAST(systemlastedittime AS DATE)= '2/9/2015'
```

Comment: If you are writing code, please write your answer as code in the editor so that it will be highlighted and easy to understand.